# Flex can't change file

Tags: flex-lexer

I want to process many files, so I add this at the end of my xml.l:

```
int ParseXml(char *s)
{
    int err = 0;
    XMLin = fopen(s, "r");

    if (!XMLin) {
        puts("Error on XML file opening\n");
    } else {
        XML_switch_to_buffer( XML_create_buffer( XMLin, YY_BUF_SIZE ) );
        err = XMLparse();
        XML_delete_buffer( YY_CURRENT_BUFFER );
        fclose(XMLin);
    }

    return err;
}
```

On the first execution it works (it returns 0), but on the second call it fails (it returns 1).
According to [the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html)  it should work!

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please clarify; which function is returning the values you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
int ParseXml(char *s)
{
    int err = 0;
    XMLin = fopen(s, "r");

    if (!XMLin) {
        puts("Error on XML file opening\n");
    } else {
        err = XMLparse();
        fclose(XMLin);
        XMLlex_destroy();
    }

    return err;
}
```